# Azure Ad WebApp MSGraph Value cannot be null

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm running into an issue with AzureAd/Graph configuration between Azure and Local.
I'm using Vs2019 .Net Core 5 Identity.Web 1.23   On local both in Visual Studio and stand alone exe.  I am able to connect to Graph get my roles and details when the same code is deployed to the Azure Web App I get the follow.

> Code: generalException Message: An error occurred sending the request.
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'headers')
> at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AppServicesAuthenticationInformation.GetIdToken(IDictionary`2 headers) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AppServicesAuthenticationTokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable`1 scopes, String authenticationScheme, String tenantId, String userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request) at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)<Microsoft.Identity.Web

The code in question

```
                var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                    {
                        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                            .Build();
                        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            services.AddRazorPages()
                  .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            // Add the UI support to handle claims challenges
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

app.config for reference

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.Read"
  },
```

Anything pointing me in a direction would be helpful, I have been stumped by this for a week now.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.
the azure web app was running as a managed account and because of this it could not connect to graph as the user.